# What are the differences between the following sentences?

Tags: differences

What are the differences between the following sentences?

The products are delivered.
The products have been delivered

Comment: This is useful: http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-are-and-vs-have-been/

Answer (score 0):

There's very little difference between those two sentences, although there is possibly a subtle difference in tense.

> The products are delivered.

I would say this if I have *just now* delivered the products and I wanted an air of faux formality. It's a status update - the products were previously *undelivered* but now they are *delivered*.

> The products have been delivered.

I would use this if I was referring to a delivery that either just happened or happened at some time in the past. The products could have just been delivered, or they could have been delivered three days ago. However, if I wanted to emphasise that it happened in the past, I may say "the products have *already* been delivered."

While both of your example sentences are technically correct, I would suggest that the more widely used option would be the second one: `The products have been delivered.` As is often the case though, which option you choose may depend on context.

Comment: But the first has many more uses than as a status update. *The products are delivered (on Fridays/by passenger cars/in good condition etc.)

Comment: You could apply those (except for 'on Fridays') to the second one too. I understood the question to refer to them as complete sentences on their own, but yes if used as the _start_ of sentences there's a lot more that comes into it!

Comment: And you could say *The products have been delivered on Fridays, for the last ten years*.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence describes the current state of the products. (Other states could have been finished, ordered, out of stock, depleted, gone, etc.)

The second sentence is a statement about an action that was taken on the products at some point. In this case, the action that was taken was a delivery.